# How to hide a menu from <front> page?

Tags: 7, routes

The main menu comes with 5 items.

How can I hide one items from the < front > page, i.e. 4 items are shown on front page, 5 items are shown on other pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is through CSS.

```
body.front .your-menu .list-item-identifier {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Sorry that my original question hides the < front > word. I need to hide an item from a specific page.

Comment: @ohho notice that this answer has `.front` so he did see your < front >

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have your own theme or a sub-theme you can simply use the [css injector module](https://www.drupal.org/project/css_injector) which allows you to quickly implement CSS code with great granularity. This [quick tutorial](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/css-injector/) will show you how easy in a blink of an eye. Hope that helps.